# Instagram Data For Python Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I tried accessing Instagram post reach based on the Instagram post ID found via the Graph API

```
impressions= graph.get_object(id='17881493329146188', fields='reach')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
GraphAPIError: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (reach) on node type (ShadowIGMedia)
```

Is there any way to successfully retrieve reach on Instagram posts through this Facebook API Python wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

`Reach` isn't a field on media, but on the `insights` under the object. You could do:

`impressions = graph.get_object(id='17881493329146188', fields='insights.metric(reach)')`

Depending on what type of object that is, you may need to specify `period` and other fields, e.g. `fields='insights.metric(reach).period(lifetime)'`